# Count the number of regular files whose filenames contain 3, 4 or 5 character in /usr/bin on the command line

Tags: linux

I'm trying to figure out how to print out the number of regular files in `/usr/bin` that contain 3,4 or 5 in the file name.

This is what I have so far: `ls /usr/bin | grep [*3*4*5*] | wc -l`

This lists all the files containing 3, 4, or 5 but I don't know how to only get files of type regular.  All I know is I need to implement "`stat -c %F`" somehow.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your own approach is one way of going about it. Another way would be to use `find`.

```
find /usr/bin/ -type f -name '*[345]*' | wc -l
```